# Calculate the maximum time taken per group

Tags: r, time, group-by, max

| Type | Start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vegetarian | 2022-06-01 00:00:04 | 2022-06-01 00:02:38 |
| Vegetarian | 2022-06-01 00:00:56 | 2022-06-01 00:10:45 |
| Non Vegetarian | 2022-06-01 00:01:39 | 2022-06-01 00:35:04 |
| Vegetarian | 2022-06-01 00:01:12 | 2022-06-01 00:20:00 |
| Non Vegetarian | 2022-06-01 00:02:38 | 2022-06-01 08:05:23 |

```
data1$len <- round(difftime(data1$end_date, data1$start_date, units='mins'))
```

| Type | start_date | end_date | len |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vegetarian | 2022-06-01 00:00:04 | 2022-06-01 00:02:38 | 3 mins |
| Vegetarian | 2022-06-01 00:00:56 | 2022-06-01 00:10:45 | 10 mins |
| Non Vegetarian | 2022-06-01 00:01:39 | 2022-06-01 00:35:04 | 33 mins |
| Vegetarian | 2022-06-01 00:01:12 | 2022-06-01 00:20:00 | 19 mins |
| Non Vegetarian | 2022-06-01 00:02:38 | 2022-06-01 08:05:23 | 483 mins |

```
library(dplyr)

data1 %>% group_by(Type) %>% summarise(max_len = max(data1$len))
```

The result I got:

| Type | max_len |
| --- | --- |
| Vegetarian | 483 mins |
| Non Vegetarian | 483 mins |

**Expected Result**

| Type | max_len |
| --- | --- |
| Vegetarian | 19 mins |
| Non Vegetarian | 483 mins |

#### data

```
data1 <- structure(list(Type = c("Vegetarian", "Vegetarian", "Non Vegetarian", 
"Vegetarian", "Non Vegetarian"), start_date = c("2022-06-01 00:00:04", 
"2022-06-01 00:00:56", "2022-06-01 00:01:39", "2022-06-01 00:01:12", 
"2022-06-01 00:02:38"), end_date = c("2022-06-01 00:02:38", "2022-06-01 00:10:45", 
"2022-06-01 00:35:04", "2022-06-01 00:20:00", "2022-06-01 08:05:23"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Your syntax using dplyr is wrong, you shouldn’t use `$` when piping. `data1 %>% group_by(Type) %>%
    summarize(max_len = max(len))`. I would also advise you don’t assign the results to the value `c` as that is a preexisting function in R that could cause confusion

Comment: PS: I used `dput(data1)` to edit your question, it's the way we share data here and provides more focus on your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` of base R, it's just a one-liner.

```
aggregate(round(difftime(end_date, start_date, units='mins')) ~ Type, data1, max)
#             Type round(difftime(end_date, start_date, units = "mins"))
# 1 Non Vegetarian                                              483 mins
# 2     Vegetarian                                               19 mins
```

Comes out little nicer with classic (i.e. without formula) interface.

```
with(data1, aggregate(list(max_len=round(difftime(end_date, start_date, units='mins'))), list(Type=Type), max))
#             Type  max_len
# 1 Non Vegetarian 483 mins
# 2     Vegetarian  19 mins
```